# DOM modification after drag and drop using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm new to jQuery.  I have implemented a drag and drop scenario.  My question is if jQuery automatically modifies the internal DOM after a succesfull drag and drop action is performed.

This is my scenario. Initially my dropable element #droppableContainer  is empty. But after I dropped some elements into it, the droppable element is still empty!!!

Below is some test code I wrote to iterate through all children elements of my droppable:

```
$('#droppableContainer').children().each(function(item) {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

The above test code is executed separately, after all draggable and droppable events, but nothing gets printed.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How do you ensure the code you posted, that iterates over the droppable children, is run **only after** all the drag-drop actions have finished executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the droppable container in the `drop` event of the droppable element:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#droppableContainer" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log($(this)); // $(this) being the #droppableContainer
        }
    });
});​
```